# Orthonormal basis of a complex double integral where deg <= 1

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

$Let\ V_{n}= \{ p \in \mathbb{C} [z]\ |\ deg(p) \leq n\}$. Complex numbers are to be written as $\ z = x + iy $ and for $\ p,q \in V_{n}$ we define

$ \langle p,q \rangle := \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} p(z) \overline{q(z)} \,dx \,dy$

Determine an Orthonormalbasis of $ (V_1, \langle -,-\rangle)$

I've tried this with the basis $ \{1,i,t,it\}$ where t is a real number and Gram Schmidt.

The first orthonormal basis would be 1. Which is also 1 normalized.
The second orthonormal basis would be 2i. But this isn't orthogonal. So there has to be a mistake there.

Then I've tried it with $ \{ 1,z\}$ where z is defined as in the question. (also with Gram Schmidt)

Again, the first orthonormal basis would be 1. Which is also 1 normalized.
The second would be $ z + i/2 - 1/2 = x + iy + i/2 - 1/2$. This also isn't orthogonal.

Can someone point out my mistake or tell me which basis i should use?

Comment: Looks like a sign error. Unnormalized it should be $z - i/2 - 1/2$.

Comment: Oh, yeah that's it. It was because when we defined unitary spaces we switched the 1 and 2 Argument and I was using the Gram Schmidt which is defined for non switched Arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because when we defined unitary spaces we switched the 1 and 2 Argument and I was using the Gram Schmidt which is defined for non switched Arguments.